# How to initialize C Union structure members (using C89 Standard XC32 compiler2.5)?

Tags: structure, union, element, initializing

I have this union / structure

```
#define HOT_INI_DATA_SIZE  14   
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t OVER_LOAD_TEMP_BYTE_LOW;
        uint8_t OVER_LOAD_TEMP_BYTE_HI;
        uint8_t TEMP_CORRECTION_BYTE_LOW;
        uint8_t TEMP_CORRECTION_BYTE_HI;
        uint8_t STEAM_CORRECTION_BYTE;
        uint8_t LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[HOT_INI_DATA_SIZE - 5];
    } fields;
    
    uint8_t bytes[HOT_INI_DATA_SIZE];
} hot_cal_data_t;
```

I am trying to initalise it with carious methods but have no luck:

```
    const hot_cal_data_t initialisationHotData =
{
    {0xD4},
    {3},
    {0},
    {0},
    {0},
    {16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16 }
};
```

It is complaining about extra braces around initializer but when I remove it the error changes.
When I try the newer C99 method:

```
{ 
    {.fields.OVER_LOAD_TEMP_BYTE_LOW = 0xD4}, 
    {.fields.OVER_LOAD_TEMP_BYTE_HI = 0x00},
    ... 
};
```

it tells me the .fields is not recognized. so I have to assume that it uses the C98 method of only initializing the first union element.

Can anyone please tell me the correct syntax to get this initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I have since figured it out.
It is using C89 standard and requires this syntax to initialize:

```
const hot_cal_data_t initialisationHotData =
{
    {
        0xD4,
        0x03,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        {
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[0]
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[1]
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[2]
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[3]
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[4]
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[5]
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[6]
            16, //.LEVEL_SENSOR_CALIBR_DATA[7]
            16  //[8]
        }
    }
};
```